# Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock Window.Print not working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing, registerclientscriptblock

Basically, I have this line of code that doesn't work in IE, but works in FF and Chrome just fine.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "RunPrintReport", "<script language='JavaScript'>window.print();</script>")
```

I don't get any errors, just doesn't work.  If I change to

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "RunPrintReport", "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('this is a test');</script>")
```

the alert comes up just fine, any idea why the window.print wouldn't work?  I've also written into another function and tried just calling that function containing a window.print();return false; to no avail as well as just including that in the RegisterClientScriptBlock.  No idea why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it slightly. I took out your script tags and added True as the last parameter. Asp will generate the script tags for you.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "RunPrintReport", "window.print();",true);
```

I tried and this works in Chrome, I.E 10 and I.E 8. One note is when opening in Internet Exploder the print dialog took a couple seconds to open.